# How I can set MAAS to download boot-image for nodes from local storage not internet

Tags: 16.04, maas, pxe

OS: ubuntu 16.05

MAAS : 2.0.0 beta 3


There is boot-image setting for nodes in MAAS settion GUI, how can I use local storage for downloading the boot-image for Nodes through PXE booting and enlisting, nodes try to connect internet to get some data?

Answer (score 0):

PXE images are loaded from your MAAS server, but when booted, they are using an Ubuntu archive mirror to download/update some packages.

You can set up local Ubuntu archive mirror and then change MAAS > Settings > Ubuntu accordingly.